# Grouping images in a RecyclerView row if they are in a sequence of 4 or more

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, whatsapp

I have a WhatsApp like chat in my application and recently they added a new functionality that groups images in albums if they are sent in a sequence of 4 or more pictures and there aren't messages between them. Like in the picture below:

[image]

So I have implemented my RecyclerView adapter that displays all the contents separately which means that whether it's a message, an image, an audio, etc, each one of them would be in a separated row in my adapter. So I would like to do what WhatsApp did and implement this grouping of images into albums if there are more than 4 sent in a row. How can I achieve this?

I have successfully implemented the `getItemViewType()` method in my adapter and it's working fine. But I don't know what to do now.

PS: Feed is my object that can be either a text message, an image, and audio file, etc. So mItems is a List of Feed.

This is my Adapter:

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseSkeletonAdapter<Feed> implements FeedHolder.FeedHolderListener{
  private static final int HOLDER_COMMENT = 1;
  private static final int HOLDER_IMAGE = 2;
  private static final int HOLDER_FILE = 3;
  private static final int HOLDER_AUDIO = 4;
  private static final int HOLDER_MARKER = 5;
  private static final int HOLDER_EMPTY = 6;

  private final FeedItemListener mListener;
  private final int mAvatarSize;
  private final String mUserId;
  private final int mPictureSize;
  private final int mSkeletonColor;

  public FeedAdapter(FeedItemListener listener, String userId, int avatarSize, int pictureSize, int skeletonColor) {
    super(2);
    mListener = listener;
    mUserId = userId;
    mAvatarSize = avatarSize;
    mPictureSize = pictureSize;
    mSkeletonColor = skeletonColor;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType){
      case HOLDER_COMMENT:
      case HOLDER_IMAGE:
        System.out.println("It is an image!");
      case HOLDER_FILE:
      case HOLDER_MARKER:
      case HOLDER_AUDIO:
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_feed, parent, false);
        return new FeedHolder(view, this, mPictureSize);
      case HOLDER_EMPTY:
      default:
        View empty = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_empty, parent, false);
        return new EmptyPlaceholderViewHolder(empty, R.string.placeholder_feed_empty_title, R.string.placeholder_feed_empty_description, R.drawable.ic_feed_placeholder);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBind(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(!(holder instanceof EmptyPlaceholderViewHolder)){
      Feed feed = mItems.get(position);
      //for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
      //  System.out.println("Tamanho: " + mItems.size() + "\nDado: " + mItems.get(i).getText() + "\nDado 2: " + mItems.get(i).getUrl());
      //}
      if (holder instanceof FeedHolder) {
        if (mUserId.equals(feed.getCreatedById())) {
          ((FeedHolder) holder).onBind(feed, mUserId, mAvatarSize);
        }else {
          ((FeedHolder) holder).onBind(feed, mUserId, mAvatarSize);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBind(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
      onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }else {

      if (holder instanceof FeedHolder) {
        ((FeedHolder) holder).onBind(mItems.get(position), payloads, mUserId, mAvatarSize);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void setHolderSkeleton(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    if (holder instanceof FeedHolder) {
      ((FeedHolder) holder).setHolderSkeleton(R.drawable.rounded_skeleton, mSkeletonColor);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void clearHolderSkeleton(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    if (holder instanceof FeedHolder) {
      ((FeedHolder) holder).clearHolderSkeleton();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(mSkeletonMode){
      return HOLDER_COMMENT;
    } if (mItems != null && mItems.size() > 0 && position >= 0 && position < mItems.size()) {
      Feed feed = mItems.get(position);
      if (feed != null) {
        String type = feed.getFeedType();
        if (type != null) {
          switch (type) {
            case FEED_IMAGE:
              return HOLDER_IMAGE;
            case FEED_AUDIO:
              return HOLDER_AUDIO;
            case FEED_FILE:
              return HOLDER_FILE;
            case FEED_MARKER:
              return HOLDER_MARKER;
            case FEED_COMMENT:
            default:
              return HOLDER_COMMENT;
          }
        }
      }
      return HOLDER_COMMENT;
    }else {
      return HOLDER_EMPTY;
    }
  }

  public List<Feed> getItems() {
    return mItems;
  }

  public void swap(List<Feed> feedList) {
    if (mItems == null) {
      mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    mItems.clear();
    mItems.addAll(feedList);
  }

  @Override
  public void toggleLike(final int pos){
    if(mListener != null && pos >= 0 && pos < mItems.size()){
      mListener.toggleLike(mItems.get(pos));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onLongClick(final int pos, final View v) {
    if (mListener != null && pos >= 0 && pos < mItems.size()) {
      mListener.onLongClick(mItems.get(pos), v);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int onAudioActionClicked(final int pos, final int progress) {
    if (mListener != null) {
      return mListener.onAudioActionClicked(pos, mItems.get(pos), progress);
    }else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(int pos) {
    if (mItems!=null && pos >= 0 && pos<mItems.size()) {
      Feed feed = mItems.get(pos);
      if (feed != null && mListener != null) {
        mListener.onClick(feed);
      }
    }
  }

  public interface FeedItemListener {
    void toggleLike(@NonNull Feed feed);
    void onLongClick(@NonNull Feed feed, @NonNull View v);
    void onClick(@NonNull Feed feed);
    int onAudioActionClicked(int pos, @NonNull Feed feed, final int progress);
  }
}
```

And this is my FeedHolder class:

```
public class FeedHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
  public static final String SEEK_BAR_PROGRESS_BUNDLE = "bundle_seek_bar_progress";
  public static final String ACTION_ICON_BUNDLE = "bundle_icon";
  public static final String RESET_AUDIO = "bundle_reset_audio";

  private static final int MINE_BG_COLOR = R.color.feed_mine_bg;
  private static final int MINE_TEXT_COLOR = R.color.feed_mine_text;
  private static final int MINE_PLAY_ICON = R.drawable.ic_play_white_24dp;
  private static final int MINE_FILE_ICON = R.drawable.ic_file_white_18dp;

  private static final int THEIR_BG_COLOR = R.color.feed_others_bg;
  private static final int THEIR_TEXT_COLOR = R.color.feed_others_text;
  private static final int THEIR_PLAY_ICON = R.drawable.ic_play_black_24dp;
  private static final int THEIR_FILE_ICON = R.drawable.ic_file_black_18dp;

  private final SimpleDraweeView mAvatar;
  private final TextView mCreator;
  private final TextView mDate;
  private final CardView mCardView;
  private final TextView mText;
  private final TextView mLike;
  private final FeedHolderListener mListener;
  private final SimpleDraweeView mPicture;
  private final int mSize;
  private final View mAudioLayout;
  private final ImageButton mAudioAction;
  private final SeekBar mAudioBar;
  private final TextView mAudioLength;

  public FeedHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final FeedHolderListener listener, final int size) {
    super(itemView);
    mAvatar = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    mCreator = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.creator);
    mDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
    mCardView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    mLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    mPicture = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    mLike.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAudioLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.audioLayout);
    mAudioAction = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audioAction);
    mAudioBar = (SeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audioBar);
    mAudioLength = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.length);

    mAudioAction.setOnClickListener(this);

    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mPicture.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    mListener = listener;
    mSize = size;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.like) {
      v.setEnabled(false);
      v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          v.setEnabled(true);
        }
      }, 1000);
      if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.toggleLike(getAdapterPosition());
      }
    }else if(id == R.id.audioAction) {
      if (mListener != null) {
        mAudioAction.setImageResource(mListener.onAudioActionClicked(getAdapterPosition(), mAudioBar.getProgress()));
      }
    }else {
      if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (mListener != null) {
      mListener.onLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public void onBind(@NonNull Feed feed, @NonNull final String userId, final int avatarSize){
    setCreatedBy(feed.getCreatedBy(), avatarSize);
    setCreatedAt(feed.getCreatedAt());
    setLiked(feed.isLiked(userId));
    setLikedCount(feed.getLikedCount());
    boolean mine = feed.getCreatedById().equals(userId);
    setColors(mine);

    switch (feed.getFeedType()) {
      case FEED_COMMENT:
        setText(feed.getShowingText());
        mPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
      case FEED_IMAGE:
        setText(feed.getCaption());
        setPicture(feed.getUrl(), feed.getPath(), feed.getUri());
        break;
      case FEED_FILE:
        setFile(feed, mine);
        break;
      case FEED_MARKER:
        setMarker();
        break;
      case FEED_AUDIO:
        setAudio(feed.getLength(), mine);
        break;
    }
  }

  public void onBind(@NonNull Feed feed, List<Object> payloads, @NonNull final String userId, final int avatarSize){
    Bundle bundle = (Bundle) payloads.get(0);
    UserResource createdBy = bundle.getParcelable(NAMES.Server.CREATED_BY_ID);
    boolean mine = createdBy != null && createdBy.getUserId().equals(userId);
    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
      switch (key) {
        case NAMES.Server.CREATED_AT:
          setCreatedAt(feed.getCreatedAt());
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.CREATED_BY_ID:
          if (createdBy != null) {
            setCreatedBy(createdBy, avatarSize);
            setColors(userId.equals(createdBy.getUserId()));
          }
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.TEXT:
          setText(feed.getShowingText());
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.COUNT:
          setLikedCount(bundle.getInt(NAMES.Server.COUNT, 0));
          break;
        case NAMES.MY_LIKE:
          setLiked(bundle.getBoolean(NAMES.MY_LIKE, false));
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.LENGTH:
          setAudio(bundle.getLong(NAMES.Server.LENGTH, 0), createdBy != null && createdBy.getUserId().equals(userId));
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.PLAN_ID:
          setMarker();
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.CAPTION:
          setText(bundle.getString(NAMES.Server.CAPTION));
          break;
        case NAMES.Server.URL:
        case NAMES.DB.PATH:
          String mimeType = bundle.getString(NAMES.Server.MIME_TYPE);
          if (mimeType != null && mimeType.contains(Constants.MimeType.IMAGE)) {
            setPicture(bundle.getString(NAMES.Server.URL), bundle.getString(NAMES.DB.PATH), null);
          }
          break;
        case SEEK_BAR_PROGRESS_BUNDLE:
          mAudioBar.setProgress(bundle.getInt(SEEK_BAR_PROGRESS_BUNDLE));
          mAudioAction.setImageResource(bundle.getInt(ACTION_ICON_BUNDLE));
          break;
        case RESET_AUDIO:
          resetAudio(bundle.getBoolean("mine"));
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  private void setCreatedBy(UserResource createdBy, final int avatarSize) {
    if (createdBy != null) {
      ImageLoader.newLoad(createdBy.getUrl(), Constants.Thumbnails.T72, mAvatar, avatarSize, avatarSize, R.drawable.unknown_user);
      mCreator.setText(createdBy.getName());
    }
  }

  private void setCreatedAt(@NonNull Date createdAt) {
    mDate.setText(DateUtils.formatDate(createdAt, DateUtils.COMMENT_DATE));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  private void setText(String text){
    if (text != null) {
      mText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        mText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.replace("\n", "<br>"), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
      }else {
        mText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.replace("\n", "<br>")), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
      }
    }else {
      mText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  private void setColors(boolean mine){
    Context context = mCardView.getContext();
    if (mine) {
      mCardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, MINE_BG_COLOR));
      mText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, MINE_TEXT_COLOR));
      mAudioLength.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, MINE_TEXT_COLOR));
    }else {
      mCardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, THEIR_BG_COLOR));
      mText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, THEIR_TEXT_COLOR));
      mAudioLength.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, THEIR_TEXT_COLOR));
    }
  }

  private void setLikedCount(final int count){
    mLike.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", count));
  }

  private void setLiked(final boolean isLiked){
    if (isLiked) {
      mLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_like, 0);
    }else {
      mLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_like_empty, 0);
    }
  }

  private void setPicture(final String url, final String path, final Uri uri){
    mAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(url != null) {
      mPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ImageLoader.newLoad(url, Constants.Thumbnails.T480, mPicture, mSize, mSize, R.color.white);
    }else if(path != null){
      mPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ImageLoader.newLoad(path, mPicture, mSize, mSize, R.color.white);
    }else if (uri != null) {
      mPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ImageLoader.newLoad(uri, mPicture, mSize, mSize);
    }else {
      mPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  private void setFile(@NonNull final Feed feed, final boolean mine){
    mPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mine) {
      mText.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(MINE_FILE_ICON, 0, 0, 0);
    }else {
      mText.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(THEIR_FILE_ICON, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    mText.setText(feed.getName());
  }

  private void setMarker(){
    mPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mText.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_plan_gray, 0, 0, 0);
    mText.setText(R.string.feed_marker_placeholder);
  }

  private void setAudio(final long length, final boolean mine){
    mPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (mine) {
      mAudioAction.setImageResource(MINE_PLAY_ICON);
    }else {
      mAudioAction.setImageResource(THEIR_PLAY_ICON);
    }
    mAudioLength.setText(AndroidUtils._String.audioLength(length));

    mAudioBar.setMax((int) (length / 1000) * 1000); //round
    mAudioBar.setProgress(0);
  }

  public void resetAudio(boolean mine){
    if (mine) {
      mAudioAction.setImageResource(MINE_PLAY_ICON);
      mAudioBar.setProgress(0);
    }else {
      mAudioAction.setImageResource(THEIR_PLAY_ICON);
      mAudioBar.setProgress(0);
    }
  }

  public void setHolderSkeleton(int avatarImageResource, int bgColor){
    mAvatar.setImageResource(avatarImageResource);
    mCreator.setText("");
    mCreator.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);

    mDate.setText("");
    mDate.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);

    mText.setText("");
    mText.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);

    mPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mLike.setText("");
    mLike.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
    mLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  public void clearHolderSkeleton(){
    mCreator.setBackgroundColor(0);
    mDate.setBackgroundColor(0);
    mText.setBackgroundColor(0);
    mLike.setBackgroundColor(0);
  }

  interface FeedHolderListener {
    void toggleLike(final int pos);
    void onLongClick(final int pos, final View v);
    void onClick(final int pos);
    int onAudioActionClicked(final int pos, final int progress);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For feed types, you currently have "HOLDER_COMMENT", "HOLDER_IMAGE", etc. Add a type "HOLDER_ALBUM" to this list. In `onCreateViewHolder()` you will inflate a layout that corresponds to your grouping of four or more images. Something like this:

[image]

**album_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample_image"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/albumView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/albumView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/albumView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/albumView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/albumView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/albumView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample_image"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/albumView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/albumView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/albumView3" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/albumView4Overlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/albumView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/albumView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/albumView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/albumView4"
        tools:text="+ 5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/albumView4OverlayText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample_image"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/albumView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/albumView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/albumView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/albumView4"
        tools:text="+ 5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now let's address the feed: Each image currently takes one feed position in `mItems`. You will need to map runs of four or more images to a single view holder that can them be mapped into the layout above. The easiest way to do this would be to create another variable of type `List<Feed>` that will hold all the feed entries that are not images that form part of an album plus a single position that corresponds to runs of four or more images in the original feed list. Your `RecyclerView` will be driven off of this new feed list.

---

**Demo App**

Here is a demo app that shows the technique mentioned above. I have incorporated the gist of your code for the purpose of the example. The key processing occurs in the constructor for the `RecyclerView` adapter. The code for "album_layout.xml" is shown above.

One thing to note: If the base feed changes, you will need to modify or recreate `mNewItems`.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Feed> mItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Drawable image = getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_image);
        mItems = Arrays.asList(new Feed("This is comment #1"),
                               new Feed("This is comment #2"),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed("This is comment #3"),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed("This is comment #4"),
                               new Feed("This is comment #5"),
                               new Feed("This is comment #6"),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed("This is comment #7"),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed(image),
                               new Feed("This is comment #8"),
                               new Feed("This is comment #9")
        );
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mItems);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Feed> mNewItems = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Feed> items) {
        int i = 0;
        Feed feed;
        int feedType;
        List<Feed> album; // Run of 4 or more images in items

        // Process the incoming list to consolidate runs of 4 or more images into
        // a single Feed entry.
        while (i < items.size()) {
            feed = items.get(i);
            feedType = feed.getFeedType();
            if (feedType == Feed.FEED_IS_IMAGE && (album = getAlbum(items, i)) != null) {
                feed = new Feed(album);
                i += album.size();
            } else {
                i++;
            }
            mNewItems.add(feed);
        }
    }

    // Identify runs of 4 or more images and return an album (List<Feed>) of those images.
    private List<Feed> getAlbum(List<Feed> feedList, int offset) {
        int i = offset + 1;

        while (i < feedList.size() && feedList.get(i).getFeedType() == Feed.FEED_IS_IMAGE) {
            i++;
        }
        return (i - offset < 4) ? null : feedList.subList(offset, i);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int layoutId;

        switch (viewType) {
            case Feed.FEED_IS_IMAGE:
                layoutId = R.layout.image_layout;
                break;

            case Feed.FEED_IS_ALBUM:
                layoutId = R.layout.album_layout;
                break;

            default: // comment
                layoutId = R.layout.comment_layout;
                break;
        }
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Feed feed = mNewItems.get(position);
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case Feed.FEED_IS_ALBUM:
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    holder.mAlbumViews.get(i).setImageDrawable(feed.mAlbum.get(i).mDrawable);
                }
                holder.mAlbumImageCount.setText("+ " + (feed.mAlbum.size() - 4));
                break;

            case Feed.FEED_IS_IMAGE:
                holder.mImage.setImageDrawable(feed.mDrawable);
                break;

            default:
                holder.mComment.setText(feed.mComment);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mNewItems.get(position).getFeedType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNewItems.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImage;
        TextView mComment;
        List<ImageView> mAlbumViews;
        TextView mAlbumImageCount;

        ViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            switch (viewType) {
                case Feed.FEED_IS_IMAGE:
                    mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    break;

                case Feed.FEED_IS_ALBUM:
                    mAlbumViews = new ArrayList<>();
                    mAlbumViews.add((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumView1));
                    mAlbumViews.add((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumView2));
                    mAlbumViews.add((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumView3));
                    mAlbumViews.add((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumView4));
                    mAlbumImageCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumView4OverlayText);
                    break;

                default: // is comment layout
                    mComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Feed.java**

```
class Feed {
    String mComment;
    Drawable mDrawable;
    List<Feed> mAlbum;

    Feed(Drawable drawable) {
        mDrawable = drawable;
    }

    Feed(List<Feed> album) {
        mAlbum = album;
    }

    Feed(String comment) {
        mComment = comment;
    }

    int getFeedType() {
        if (mDrawable != null) {
            return FEED_IS_IMAGE;
        }
        if (mAlbum != null) {
            return FEED_IS_ALBUM;
        }
        return FEED_IS_COMMENT;
    }

    final static int FEED_IS_COMMENT = 1;
    final static int FEED_IS_IMAGE = 2;
    final static int FEED_IS_ALBUM = 3;
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.albumwork.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**comment_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="A comment" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**image_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried to something similar to what you suggested. But now I am using a List<List<Feed>> to handle the group of images. The problem I am facing right now is that my recyclerView is not loading the data properly. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818205/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-view-holder-adapter-positionviewhol

Comment: @MarcosGuimaraes I read your other post. `List<List<Feed>>` may work, but may be a little involved. Why not just have ` `List<image>` to hold your images that is part of the new album holder that I recommended? (I don't know how your a keeping your images, so I just have "image" above.) Then when you do the bind, you just need to load up the `ImageView` with your images.

Comment: But how can I use List<Feed> for the type image if I am passing a list of feed to my adapter?

Comment: getItemViewType only works for one item each time, right? How can I make it deal with all of the images in a row at the same time?

Comment: @MarcosGuimaraes You are right if you are talking about your `mItems`. In `mItems` a run of 6 images, let's say, has 6 entries. What I am suggesting is that you process `mItems` into a new list, say, `mNewItems` also a `List<Feed>`. In `mNewItems` a run of 6 images will be consolidated into one entry. You will have to make a new type of entry that corresponds to this "album." In that new entry, you will can have another `List<Feed>` that points back to the image entries in `mItems`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks for your helpful answer, but I have a problem with pagination, how can we fix it? my RecyclerView fills with a list of messages that came from the server in pagination way, each page has 50 messages. do you have any suggestions for chat?